# Set Google Storage cache-control metadata to allow transform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Hope every is doing great. I am upload files using google storage utility to file with gzip compression enable

```
gsutil -h 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -h 'Cache-Control:Cache-Control:public,max-age=3600' cp -z filejson gs://{bucket_name}/{id}/{id}/file.json
```

Issue is by default when I use this command to upload files, it's set file metadata cache control to no-transform. When I down this file on client (like browser).I can read the content of the file. Is there any way I can allow tranform to object metadata. So it will work fine on clients.

Answer (score 0):

From the **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta):**

This can be achieved using `gsutil setmeta`. The `gsutil setmeta` command allows you to set or remove the metadata on one or more objects.

> **By default, publicly readable objects are served with a Cache-Control header allowing such objects to be cached for 3600 seconds. For more details about this default behavior see the CACHE-CONTROL section of gsutil help metadata. As the example shows:**

```
 gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" \
       -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" cp -r images \
       gs://bucket/images
```

> **On the other hand, if you need to ensure that updates become visible immediately, you should set a Cache-Control header of "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" on such objects. You can do this with the example command:**

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/html" \
  -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" gs://bucket/*.html
```

You can learn more about Cache-Control [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control)

Comment: .In case issue is with the no-transform metadata added to object by default using gsutil . Which set the no-transform on each object . I looking that work around

Comment: Hi @FahadAbid, from what I understand, what you mean is that you would like publicly readable objects (please notice that non-public data cannot be cacheable) to be cached for 3600 seconds. Is this correct? If so, you would use the `gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600"` command. Optional: you may use the -m to activate a parallel update, in case you have a lot of objects. Otherwise, let me know.

Comment: my issue is with transform of upload file . I upload text file with -z (gzip enabled) but wen downloaded on client it come as gzip which should be decompressed. Meta-data value no-transform tell bucket to not decompress at a time of download .

Comment: If files are stored as gzip-compressed objects on Cloud Storage, they can be automatically decompressed before being sent to a requester. In order to be eligible for decompressive transcoding, your file must meet the following criteria: the file is gzip-compressed when stored in Cloud Storage, as well as the associated metadata includes Content-Encoding: gzip (which you already did using the -z parameter). If this still does not resolve your issue, then you will need to modify your metadata using the `gsutil setmeta` command on already-uploaded objects to modify "no-transform". Link above.

Comment: In case my suggestion was helpful to you, please consider upvoting and marking my answer as accepted for greater visibility to the community. Thank you @FahadAbid

Comment: Moreover, I noticed that you are using `Cache-Control:Cache-Control:public`, as stated in your question, when it should be `Cache-Control:public`. Please make sure you are using the correct syntax when using the `gsutil` command.

Comment: it's possibile to use public with max-age 0 instead private?
Ex. "Cache-Control: **public** , max-age=0, no-transform" ??